# FileUtils.copyFile() VS FileChannel.transferTo()

Tags: java, android, file-copying, fileutils, filechannel

As I found, underlying OS call for the `copyToFile()` is `Libcore.os.read(fd, bytes, byteOffset, byteCount)`, while `transferTo()` is based on memory mapped file:

```
MemoryBlock.mmap(fd, alignment, size + offset, mapMode);
...
buffer = map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, position, count);
return target.write(buffer);
```

Q1: Am I right or wrong in my findings?
Q2: Is there any reason to use `FileUtils.copyFile()` as `FileChannel.transferTo()` seems should be more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I informed a bit about this and have this conclusion:

4 ways to copy files in java

1. Copy file using apache commons IO
2. Copy file using `java.nio.file.Files.copy()`

   > This method is pretty much fast and simple to write.
3. Copy file using `java.nio.channels.FileChannel.transferTo()`

**If you are fond of channel classes for their brilliant performance, use this method.**

```
private static void fileCopyUsingNIOChannelClass() throws IOException 
{
    File fileToCopy = new File("c:/temp/testoriginal.txt");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToCopy);
    FileChannel inChannel = inputStream.getChannel();

    File newFile = new File("c:/temp/testcopied.txt");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    FileChannel outChannel = outputStream.getChannel();

    inChannel.transferTo(0, fileToCopy.length(), outChannel);

    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

4. Copy file using FileStreams (If you are struck in older java versions, this one is for you.)

Comment: PurpleSoft, thanks a lot. However, I can't find the Files class in android. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: Should be, look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) , check your libraries and imports

Comment: It's 'File' not 'File**s**'. Also it has no the copy() method.

Comment: Android is Java 6 based, and there is no backport of Java 7's java.nio.file classes to Android. sorry
More info: [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html)

Comment: Would have been nice to see example snippets of each case. In addition, in Java 8, case (3) give the following gradle compiler issue: `Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed`.